# Bitnami ruby stack AMI instance

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, bitnami

Apologies if I am being completely stupid here. I have 1-click-launched Ruby Stack from bitnami onto AWS (not via bitnami at this stage). I have a keypair setup on my AWS account which I've downloaded. I'm attempting to ssh using the private key from the pair e.g.

> ssh -i pk-…..pem.txt ubuntu@54.206.51.13

I get

> "Permission denied (public key)."

(note I have chmod 600 the keys)

everything I'm finding online is about using a different username e.g. ubuntu v bitnami. but nowhere does it confirm if it is indeed the private key of the key pair (which is actually associated with CloudFront). most examples involve downloading the pem key from the bitnami console, not about what keys to use with the bitnami AMI image.

Hope someone can clarify I'm doing something dumb and can't see past it.

Ben

Answer (score 1):

Note the user for Bitnami images is "bitnami" so if you are using the correct private key you should be able to log in the machine with the following command:

> ssh -i /path/to/private-key.pem bitnami@ec2-xx-yy-zz.amazonaws.com

If you are on Windows note that you have to convert your PEM key to PPK format. There is a good guide about how to convert it at http://wiki.bitnami.com/Amazon_cloud/how_to_connect_to_your_amazon_instance#How_can_I_get_my_private_SSH_key_in_PPK_format.3f

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks Beltran. I did try this originally (on my mac using pem format ). Non luck 
I finally got it working having generate my own new key pair. For some reason the pair on Aws refuses to work. Not sure why.
I can only assume the keys on the server somehow got out of sync.